# How do I properly Shrinkwrap in a crease?

Tags: modeling, shrinkwrap

I´m rather new to Blender and tried using the shrinkwrap modifier more, I can get it to work just fine on simple forms, but when there is a crease it always just makes a bridge as the closes vertices are not the ones in the crease.
Is it even possible to shrinkwrap in a way so that a crease is not bridged over? If so, what would the setup of the Shrinkwrap be?

Comment: try adding more geometry to the wrapper by using subdivison surface modifier.
also a screenshot of issue is more appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

As Nand 27 says above, make sure you have at least enough geometry to work with on the source object.  I have a plane that I subdivided so that it's about a 24x24 grid.  Then, did you try different modes?  For example, this is using the "Nearest Surface" mode:

[image]

But this is using "Project" mode, which projects onto the surface:

[image]

As you can see, in this case, the "Project" nicely follows the shape of the indentation, whereas "Nearest Surface" had trouble finding the corner.